# Run a shell script from another script concurrently in a new terminal window

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I'm trying to run a shell script from another and make them display each script's output in a separate terminal window but I cannot. When I run script1 it runs fine and then calls script2 using `source` so that I have access to the variables in script1 but after script2 is called I lose the output of script1 on terminal. Any advice how to open a new terminal for script2 once it's called and then script1 continue what's it's doing without waiting for script2 to finish so that they can run both in separate windows?

This is script1:

```
#!/bin/bash -i
#

alias brc='source ~/.bashrc'
id='myapp1*'

dir_list= a directory list I have


only_once=0

select dir in $dir_list; do
    dir1= My directory 1
    while :; do
        echo "#### entered while ####"
        #here I do my operations

        if [ $only_once -eq 0 ]; then
            echo "entered"
            source path to my script2
            only_once=$((only_once+1))
        fi

        sleep 5m
        echo ""
    done
    break
done
```

And this is script2:

```
#!/bin/bash -i
#
echo $id
newdir= get a specific directory here
echo $newdir
cd  $newdir
for f in ./Myapps_*
    do
        cd ./$f/Data
            for i in *.app
                do
                    echo "############################"
                    echo "Fetchingggg" $i

                        echo "############################"
                done
        cd ../../
    done
```

Comment: Maybe this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593724/redirect-stderr-stdout-of-a-process-after-its-been-started-using-command-lin/593764#593764 can help.

Answer (score -1):

Tried increasing the buffer on your terminal?

[In terminal edit>profiles>edit>scrolling tab](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=869028&p=5450110#post5450110)

Comment: This has nothing to do with my question.

Comment: "...but after script2 is called I lose the output of script1 on terminal."